# How can I override the title of an included Toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a problem in overriding an attribute of an included layout.

I have a base Toolbar layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.me" 
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_homeview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" 
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/bright_foreground_material_dark" 
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:title="@string/homeview_title"
    app:subtitle="@string/homeview_sub_title">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am including the above layout in the layout below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.me" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<include 
    android:id="@+id/homeview_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/homeview_toolbar_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     />
``</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to override the app:title attribute but it just does not work. I get an error 
`Unexpected namespace prefix app found for tag include`

What could be the issue here?

Comment: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.me"`

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: where did you put it ?

Comment: I replaced .../res/org.me with .../res-auto

Comment: You need to do it in both the files

Comment: `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
     android:id="@+id/toolbar_homeview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" 
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
     android:background="@color/bright_foreground_material_dark" 
     android:elevation="4dp"
     app:title="@string/homeview_title"
     app:subtitle="@string/homeview_sub_title">
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <include 
        android:id="@+id/homeview_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/homeview_toolbar_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         />
</LinearLayout>
`

Comment: why do u want app:title ?title is automaticaclly shown !

Comment: I want a base implementation of toolbar which will be included in the toolbars used in different activities. Each toolbar should have a different title and subtitile

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this. I want you to simple Copy-Paste the whole thing, to reduce typo errors. If you still get some exception let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/homeview_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/homeview_toolbar_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar_homeview"
                               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                               android:background="@color/bright_foreground_material_dark"
                               android:elevation="4dp"
                               android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                               app:subtitle="@string/homeview_sub_title"
                               app:title="@string/homeview_title">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I did what you wrote but I still cant override the `app:title` attribute inside homeview_toolbar in the `<include>` tag

Comment: You have two layouts here. Could you mention the file names of these xml's ?

Comment: The first is `homeview_toolbar_base.xml` which contains `android:id="@+id/toolbar_homeview"` and the second is `homeview_toolbar.xml` which contains the `<include/> tag` which includes `homeview_toolbar_base.xml` and tries to override app:title which is the problem.